# Is the product of a Schwartz function and a locally integrable function integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of rapidly decreasing functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is $fg$ integrable? Namely is it true that 
$$
\int |fg| <\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pick $n=1$, $f(x)=\xi(x)e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x)=e^{x^2}$, where $\xi \equiv 0$ near $x=0$. But even $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, as Daniel Fischer points out in a comment.

Here the point is that any continuous function is locally integrable, and $f$ cannot compete with functions that blow up at infinity faster than polynomials.

Comment: $e^{-\lvert x\rvert}$ isn't differentiable, the Schwartz space consists of smooth functions. Pick $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, the effect remains.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you!